# Why do I have to type `sudo` before every pip install?

Tags: python, macos, pip

When installing packages, logged as my username, I always get permission denied unless I do:

`sudo pip install`.

How can I make it so this is not necessary? Or is this supposed to be like that?

Comment: It's best like that, as it forces you to produce the password (anti-hacking) and make you check that it won't destroy your system (anti-accident). However, if you don't want to have to type sudo, use a root shell, but BE CAREFUL!

Comment: OR you can use the --user mode, or you can use a distribution (e.g., anaconda) that is not by default placed in system directories.

Comment: you are installing the packages system-wide. It's good practice using [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). You can look into this.

Comment: Other alternatives include making the system-wide site-packages group-writable, installing another Python in your user space instead of system-wide, and installing another Python system-wide but making _its_ system-wide site-packages group-writable (which Homebrew does for you by default) so you don't screw up Apple's pre-installed Python.

Comment: It may be worth reading the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ) for an interesting discussion of why you may or may not want to rely on Unix protections for this kind of stuff. Of course it's slanted toward the conclusion that you _don't_ want to do so, because that's the choice they made, but it's worth reading anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Either, I would use virtualenv, as mentioned in comments to the question, or, leverage python's PYTHON_USERBASE to install modules only for your user:

In your .bashrc add:

```
export PYTHON_USERBASE=~/python_userbase
```

then download your package, extract it, go inside the resulting dir, and run:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

or simply use:

```
pip install <package> --user
```

They'll all end up in ~/python_userbase/lib/pythonXXX/site-packages and not damage your system's site-packages

Reference:

[pep-0370](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)

The last thing, this time, Unix related, you could modify /etc/sudoers and grant your user the rights to execute pip as root. But I would highly discourage you from doing this.

Comment: You shall accept this answer and click the check icon, I'd appreciate that. Thanks