# Python 2.7 imports module from wrong location

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, openpyxl

I'm on Python 2.7.6 un Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to import openpyxl. I upraged to a recent version via `sudo pip install openpyxl --upgrade` and `pip show openpyxl` gives the following output:

```
pip show openpyxl
---
Name: openpyxl
Version: 2.3.3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

However, when inside python, after I `import openpyxl` It seems to load it from a different location: `/usr/lib` instead of `/usr/local/lib`

```
openpyxl.__version__
'1.7.0'
openpyxl.__file__
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openpyxl/__init__.pyc'
```

I have set the `$PYTHONPATH` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

And when looking at `sys.path` I get this output:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',... and 12 other locations]
```

It seems to have my desired location in first. Nevertheless the wrong module gets loaded.

**EDIT:**

Contents of `$PATH`:

```
/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/build/x86_64-gcc4.8/release/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/build/x86_64-gcc4.8/debug/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/build/x86_64-gcc4.8/bin:/home/maid/phd/3rdpartySoft/art-2009-03-12/bin:/home/maid/phd/3rdpartySoft/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/build/x86_64-gcc4.8/release/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/build/x86_64-gcc4.8/debug/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/build/x86_64-gcc4.8/bin:/home/maid/phd/3rdpartySoft/art-2009-03-12/bin:/home/maid/phd/3rdpartySoft/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:.:/home/maid/bin:/misc/software-lin/matlabR2015a/bin:/home/maid/phd/3rdpartySoft/nifty_reg-1.3/niftyreg_install/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/cudatoolkit-3.2.16-x86_64/cuda/bin:/misc/database/cv2/local/bin:/misc/software-lin/vibez/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin:/misc/software-lin/vivi:/home/maid/localsoft/voreen/voreen-src-3.0.1-unix/bin/:/home/maid/tmp/ij146/ImageJ:.:/home/maid/bin:/misc/software-lin/matlabR2015a/bin:/home/maid/phd/3rdpartySoft/nifty_reg-1.3/niftyreg_install/bin:/misc/software-lin/lmbsoft/cudatoolkit-3.2.16-x86_64/cuda/bin:/misc/database/cv2/local/bin:/misc/software-lin/vibez/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin:/misc/software-lin/vivi:/home/maid/localsoft/voreen/voreen-src-3.0.1-unix/bin/:/home/maid/tmp/ij146/ImageJ
```

Any help appreciated, 
thanks, Dominic

Comment: That is is indeed weird, no clue why is it ignoring it. What if you try with a simlink just for troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have administrative rights and the guy who has comes back on monday (university). But just to get it right: you mean a symlink to point `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/` -->  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` ?

Comment: no to point directly to the py file, but yes make the one in /usr/lib in /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 0):

I posit that if you `echo $PATH` you will find that `/usr/lib` is being searched before `/usr/local/lib`. Because it finds it in `/usr/lib` first, it will not go on to look in `/usr/local/lib`.

`sys.path` only covers the `$PYTHONPATH` variable and doesn't show you the contents of `$PATH`.

Comment: Also, check which version of Python pip is working with. On Debian I think it's best to build your own Python and use that for your packages.

Comment: pip is version `1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. `$PATH` doesn't have either of the above mentioned in it. I unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which made some problems.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of $PATH? When you are "inside" Python are you using sudo?

Comment: I edited the question. No, I'm not sudoing, with "inside" I refer to the interactive mode. Same happens when I call a .py script with a main - method. ... lol apparently double underscore makes stuff bold in a comment ;)

Comment: Why did you type `sudo` when you did `pip install openpyxl --upgrade`? Can you run it without sudo?

Comment: Use user mode for installation if it requires it. Refer to this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305396/why-do-i-have-to-type-sudo-before-every-pip-install

Comment: I (in reality my admin) used `sudo` because It didn't work without it. I guess its because pip wrote the upgrade to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Thanks for the suggestion with the user mode. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by

1. removing the old `openpyxl` package via ubuntus package manager.
2. making `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` readable to all, which strangely wasn't the case before - and I hadn't noticed it.

Thanks for everyone who made effort helping me.
Dominic