# Some issues with pip installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I tried to install pip manager using the file get-pip.py as mentioned in the documentation- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

So, I downloaded the file and ran `python get-pip.py` and as a result, I had permission issues. So I again ran `sudo python get-pip.py` and it worked.

Now I wanted to install numpy. So I ran `pip install numpy` and it showed me the Import Error saying-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

But again when I ran `sudo pip install numpy`, it worked and got installed. Now, for every python script involving these pip packages, I have to run the script using `sudo` which I don't like. So how can I resolve these permission issues?

Just to mention-

python v2.7.12

pip v9.0.1

pip installation location- /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to type \`sudo\` before every pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305396/why-do-i-have-to-type-sudo-before-every-pip-install)

Comment: I can tell you on windows that when you run pip from cmd, you need to launch cmd as an administrator or it won't install due to permissions.  I bet this is the same thing.

Comment: @DSCH it may be called an extension of it. This is because, even if I install the packages using sudo, I must at least be able to used the packages installed without `sudo`. How can I do that?